# Finding the union and intersection of the following set families?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each natural number  $n$, let $A_n=\{5n,5n+1,5n+2,...,6n\}$ and let the family $L=\{A_n: n\in \Bbb N\}$.

I am not sure how to find the intersection.

Becuase I am not sure where the ellipse .... leads to.

Comment: to be clear is it $L=\{x\in A_n,\forall n\in \Bbb N\}$?

Comment: Wait I think I made an error with l

Comment: yes Now I have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_1 = \{ 5,6 \}$

$A_2 = \{ 10, 11, 12 \}$

$A_3 = \{ 15, 16, 17, 18 \}$

$A_4 = \{ 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 \}$

$A_5 = \{ 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 \}$

...

Comment: Hmm how did you get the set I think they are right, But I am a bit confused

Comment: I see so the union all natural number greater than 5 and the interseciton is empty set?

Comment: @FernandoMartinez - Ok for intersection. For the union the "missing" numbers are : $1,2,3,4,7,8,9,13,14,19$.

Comment: I see so the union it is all natural number except 1,2,3,4,7,9,13,14,19

Comment: Yes : $\bigcup L = \mathbb N \backslash \{1,2,3,4,7,9,13,14,19 \}$.